# How to write SQL query to get first and last group's row info (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have  such table:

| PersonID | ts | group | place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | group1 | place1 |
| 1 | 2023-01-03 00:00:00 | group1 | place2 |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | group2 | place3 |
| 1 | 2023-01-07 00:00:00 | group3 | place5 |
| 1 | 2023-01-10 00:00:00 | group1 | place2 |
| 1 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | group1 | place4 |
| 1 | 2023-01-21 00:00:00 | group3 | place7 |
| 1 | 2023-01-23 00:00:00 | group3 | place5 |
| 1 | 2023-01-25 00:00:00 | group3 | place7 |
| 1 | 2023-01-28 00:00:00 | group2 | place9 |

I need to write SQL for group rows by field "group", but only sequentially by timestamp, and get first and last timestamp for current "group" like this:

| PersonID | ts-start | ts-end | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-03 00:00:00 | group1 |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | group2 |
| 1 | 2023-01-07 00:00:00 | 2023-01-07 00:00:00 | group3 |
| 1 | 2023-01-10 00:00:00 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | group1 |
| 1 | 2023-01-21 00:00:00 | 2023-01-25 00:00:00 | group3 |
| 1 | 2023-01-28 00:00:00 | 2023-01-28 00:00:00 | group2 |

I use PostgreSQL 12. How I can do this?

I used window functions but didn't get the right result.

Comment: Can you also show us your window function attempt.

Comment: SELECT distinct
   PersonID,
   group,
    FIRST_VALUE(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY  PersonID,   group 
                                ORDER BY PersonID 
                               )  AS ts_start,
    LAST_VALUE(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY   PersonID,   group 
                                ORDER BY PersonID
                              )   AS ts_end
    
 FROM myTable   
ORDER BY PersonID, group, ts_start

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Gaps & Islands problem. You can use the traditional solution:

```
select
  min(personid) as personid, min(ts) as ts_start, max(ts) as ts_end, 
  min(grp) as grp
from (
  select x.*,
    sum(case when grp <> pg then 1 else 0 end)
    over(partition by personid order by ts) as g
  from (
    select t.*, lag(grp) over(partition by personid order by ts) as pg
    from t
  ) x
) y
group by g
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bSCRgk9c).